# titlesec and bibliography

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, titlesec, capitalization

I use titlesec to capitalize and display the chapter title at the center. Everything is fine until I get to the bibliography, the word 'bibliography' is not capitalized. Here is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{20pt}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{0pt}{\small}

 \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
This is a workingn example
\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{Niesen}
Niesen, Social networks/blogs now account for one in every four and a half
  minutes online,
  http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/global/social-media-accounts-for-22-perc%
ent-of-time-online/, report (June 2010).

\bibitem{AirwideSolutions}
AirwideSolutions, Mobile social networking and the rise of the smart machines -
  2015ad,
  http://www.airwidesolutions.com/whitepapers/MobileSocialNetworking.pdf, white
  paper (November 2010).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: But why should Bibliography be capitalized with your settings? You are only applying \MakeUppercase to \chaptername (that is, to the word "Chapter") and not to the actual titles.

Comment: I didn't write the titlesec settings. If I remember correctly, I asked here a while ago how to center and capitalize the chapter title and you helped me. How do I capitalize "Bibliography"? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude with my previous comment. I apologize if I gave that impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why "Bibliography" should be capitalized with your settings. You are only applying `\MakeUppercase` to `\chaptername` (i.e., to the word "Chapter") and not to the actual titles. If you want to have the word "Bibliography" capitalized you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\thebibliography` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\chapter*{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}{}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1in}{20pt}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{0pt}{\small}

 \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
 \titleformat{\subsubsection}
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
This is a workingn example
\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{Niesen}
Niesen, Social networks/blogs now account for one in every four and a half
  minutes online,
  http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/global/social-media-accounts-for-22-perc%
ent-of-time-online/, report (June 2010).

\bibitem{AirwideSolutions}
AirwideSolutions, Mobile social networking and the rise of the smart machines -
  2015ad,
  http://www.airwidesolutions.com/whitepapers/MobileSocialNetworking.pdf, white
  paper (November 2010).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]